# Independent table th row

Tags: html, css, html-table

In my table the TH is always the same length as TD.
What is the reason? I dont understand.
All I want is TH that would have width of the whole table and wouldnt change the "nick" TH width

```css
.someTable{
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
td{
    min-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<table class='someTable'>
    <tr>
        <th>table title:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nick</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colspan helps you

```
 <th colspan="3">table title:</th>
```

It wraps the number of cells that you define.

Comment: No you can't. You should select what is the best. Aaron make an snippet, but I think that I'm first :) Don't matter, I'm not envy ;)

Comment: He's got more pluses so you will get the correct answer :D

Comment: Thank you, very pleasant. :)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use colspan, to span 3 columns.

A table will always contain the same amount of `<td>` in each `<tr>` creating columns and rows.

If you want to span more table cells (ex. making a table cell expand to use two cell spaces) then you would use `colspan="XX"` with XX being the amount of columns you would like to extend the cell.

If you want to travel vertically through the table rows then you would use `rowspan="XX"`

```html
<table class='someTable'>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">table title:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nick</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you're welcome @hiamprolish If you would kindly mark my answer as correct by clicking the check mark next my answer :)